# Jersey Not Defined in Spring Cloud Edgware

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry, netflix-ribbon

I upgraded one of our Spring Boot services from looking like this in the POMs:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Dalston.SR5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

to looking this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Edgware.SR3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now we get the following error when we try to reach out to another service inside of Cloud Foundry.

```
Error creating bean with name 'ribbonRestClient' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RestClientRibbonConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.niws.client.http.RestClient]: Factory method 'ribbonRestClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
```

We are deploying our service into on premise Pivotal Cloud Foundry and we are using the Service Registry service built into PCF ("tile").

I assume I've got a botched configuration somewhere but I can't seem to figure out where.

I also think it's directly related to this commit but I can't find the resolution: [github commit](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/spring-cloud-services-starters/commit/73fa1a51e62eada6d9a22ae409a7683b24426253)

```
    2018-04-09_20:05:42.590 ERROR org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log ln182  Message: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonRestClient' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RestClientRibbonConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.niws.client.http.RestClient]: Factory method 'ribbonRestClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RestClientRibbonConfiguration.ribbonRestClient(RestClientRibbonConfiguration.java:58)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RestClientRibbonConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4a284cff.CGLIB$ribbonRestClient$0(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RestClientRibbonConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4a284cff$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ab36db6.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RestClientRibbonConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4a284cff.ribbonRestClient(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:220)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:89)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getInstance(SpringClientFactory.java:110)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1092)
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:124)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getClient(SpringClientFactory.java:51)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory.java:51)
at <custom>.RequestCorrelationClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(RequestCorrelationClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:86)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:70)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
at <custom>.JwtForwardingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(JwtForwardingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa4e9ed0.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.captureUrlTemplate(RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.java:33)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:320)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ffd02d3.getForEntity(<generated>)
at <custom>.Controller.doStuff(Controller.java:45)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at <custom>.Service.doStuff(Service.java:25)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:49)
at <custom>.doFilter(Filter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:677)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.cloudfoundry.router.ClientCertificateMapper.doFilter(ClientCertificateMapper.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
```

[maven dependency trees](https://gist.github.com/azizabah/30b4edf4fbc6d09a090cb2dbbe47370f)

*Edited to include stack trace and maven dependency trees*

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the error? It would be useful to know what code it is that's expecting `jersey-client` to be on the classpath.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - Added stack trace per request

Comment: It's the auto-configuration for Ribbon that's using Jersey. That should be unrelated to the commit you linked to that affects Eureka. What dependencies does your application have? The output of `mvn dependency:tree` before and after the upgrade would be useful.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - added link to gists with maven dependency trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, this issue is caused when configuring Ribbon to use the deprecated `RestClient`. See the [Spring Cloud Services Starters issue](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/spring-cloud-services-starters/issues/21) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You were right to suspect [this commit](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/spring-cloud-services-starters/commit/73fa1a51e62eada6d9a22ae409a7683b24426253).

In your original pom, the dependency on `io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry` resulted in a transitive dependency on `jersey-client`:

```
+- io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry:jar:1.5.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.55:compile
|  |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.55:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.6.2:compile
|  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.7:runtime
|  |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
|  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:runtime
|  |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
|  |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
|  |  |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:runtime
|  |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
|  |  |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
|  |  |  |  |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:runtime
|  |  |  |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.1:runtime
|  |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
|  |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.4:compile
|  |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:runtime
|  |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.10.1:runtime
|  |  |  |  \- com.netflix.servo:servo-internal:jar:0.10.1:runtime
|  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:runtime
|  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
|  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
|  |  |  \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.1.0:runtime
|  |  |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
```

`jersey-client` is also a transitive dependency of `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon` which is pulled in by `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`.

The exclusion that was added in the commit linked to above has resulted in the Jersey jars being excluded entirely even though Ribbon depends upon them. You should be able to work around the problem by adding an explicit dependency on
`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon` without any exclusions. However, I don't think it should be necessary for you to do so.

I'd open an issue against [Spring Cloud Services Starters](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/spring-cloud-services-starters) as it looks like the exclusion may be too broad. Either that, or it isn't intended that people use Ribbon in the manner that you are when using that starter.

Comment: Ok. I'll go ahead and open the issue. Thanks for the confirmation and work around suggestion.